# SSIS Copy files from one location to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I want to copy a specific file from one location to another. I have a Message Box that prints where the file is copied *source* and *destination* as per below:

[image]

I get the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [File.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2), The second parameter is the new file name not the directory:

> The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.

You need to use a similar logic:

```
FileCopy(filestocopy[p],targetDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filestocopy[p]));
```

Also it is recommended to check if the file already exists in the directory:

```
if (!File.Exists(targetDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filestocopy[p])))
    FileCopy(filestocopy[p],targetDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filestocopy[p]));
```

If you need to overwrite any existing file you can [add a boolean parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_):

```
FileCopy(filestocopy[p],targetDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filestocopy[p]),true);
```

Comment: Thank You very much @Yahfoufi You are a legend

Comment: @TshepisoSelepe if this answer solved the issue, you have to mark it as accepted. click on the mark on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [file directory] + [File name] + [File extension] for the target parameter

So do something like this:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(filestocopy[p]));
File.Copy(filestocopy[p], destination);
```